# How do I lift state up in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The main problem right now is sharing the quantity of each item to the cart. I've read that I have to lift the state up to App.js to achive that, but then I have no clue how to create individual quantity states for each item (Right now they are created when Item component is being rendered. I tried using .map() on items (in App.js), but it doesn't work and gives an error.
Here's some code:

1. App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import Cart from "./Components/Cart";
import Shop from "./Components/Shop";
import img1 from "./Pictures/food1.jpg";
import img2 from "./Pictures/food2.jpg";
import img3 from "./Pictures/food3.jpg";

function App() {
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Spaghetti",
      price: "300$",
      img: img1,
      alt: "Plate of Spaghetti",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Pizza",
      price: "500$",
      img: img2,
      alt: "Pizza",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Tiramisu",
      price: "150$",
      img: img3,
      alt: "Tiramisu",
    },
  ]);
  // let [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header onShowCart={() => setShowCart(!showCart)} />
      {showCart && <Cart items={items} />}
      <Shop items={items} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

2. Shop.js

```
import Item from "./Item";

const Shop = ({ items}) => {
  return (
    <div className="shop">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

3. Item.js (Here's the [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0) which I have to lift up.)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ItemInfo from "./ItemInfo";

const Item = ({ item }) => {
  let [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
  const addToCart = () => {
    console.log("Add Value");
    setQuantity(quantity + 1);
    console.log(quantity);
  };
  const removeFromCart = () => {
    console.log("Lower Value");
    quantity > 0 && setQuantity(quantity - 1);
    console.log(quantity);
  };

  return (
    <div className="item">
      <img className="image" src={item.img} alt={item.alt} />
      <ItemInfo
        name={item.name}
        price={item.price}
        onAdd={addToCart}
        onLower={removeFromCart}
        quantity={quantity}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Comment: It looks like you're using `items.map` in `Shop`, not in `App`.  What's the error that this gives you?  Where did you try to "lift state up" here?

Comment: so you want [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0) to be lifted up to App.js right? If that is the case, just do it and pass a callback to Item.js which sets the quantity

Comment: @David yes, I've given the code which makes quantity state separate for each Item. When I tried creating quantity state for each item inside App.js using .map() it gave me "useState() cannot be used inside a callback". I understand it's because of .map(), but I really don't know any other alternative.

Comment: @JakeRedgrave: Well, because hooks can't be used in callbacks.  But nowhere in the code shown are you doing that.  At a high level, if you want to track a `quantity` for each "item", wouldn't you just add it as a property on your `items` objects?

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro indeed, that's what I want. I'm sorry, but I don't really know what do you mean by "pass a callback function", what should it do exactly?

Comment: @David I'm not doing that in this code, because I've sent the "base" code from before I've started to try and achieve what I specified  in question. Maybe adding quantity as a property to each object is a solution.

Comment: React's state management is really not great for HOC type data,. it wasn't decided to be.  Redux is a common alternative, but personally I find it too verbose.  Personally I use my own with proxies, but another state management that seems much more react, is recoil -> https://recoiljs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse `items` for quantity state and then create another  function call `updateQuantity` and then pass it down to the child component `Shop`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import Cart from "./Components/Cart";
import Shop from "./Components/Shop";
import img1 from "./Pictures/food1.jpg";
import img2 from "./Pictures/food2.jpg";
import img3 from "./Pictures/food3.jpg";

function App() {
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Spaghetti",
      price: "300$",
      img: img1,
      alt: "Plate of Spaghetti",
      quantity: 0, //quantity state
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Pizza",
      price: "500$",
      img: img2,
      alt: "Pizza",
      quantity: 0, //quantity state
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Tiramisu",
      price: "150$",
      img: img3,
      alt: "Tiramisu",
      quantity: 0, //quantity state
    },
  ]);
  const updateQuantity = (updatedItem) => {
     const updatedItems = items.map(item => updatedItem === item ? {...updatedItem} : item) //update quantity from `updatedItem`
     setItems(updatedItems)
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header onShowCart={() => setShowCart(!showCart)} />
      {showCart && <Cart items={items} />}
      <Shop items={items} updateQuantity={updateQuantity}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Note that if `items` are controlled by API calls, you don't need to add `quantity: 0` directly on items

Passing `updateQuantity` down to `Shop` and

```
import Item from "./Item";

const Shop = ({ items, updateQuantity }) => {
  return (
    <div className="shop">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
          updateQuantity={updateQuantity}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

The last piece is updating your `Item` component logic

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ItemInfo from "./ItemInfo";

const Item = ({ item, updateQuantity }) => {
  const addToCart = () => {
    const currentQuantity = item.quantity || 0 //if `item.quantity` is undefined, it will use 0 as default value
    item.quantity = currentQuantity + 1
    updateQuantity(item) //lift `item` state to `App`
  };
  const removeFromCart = () => {
    if(!item.quantity) { //0 or undefined
       return //do nothing
    }
    item.quantity = item.quantity - 1
    updateQuantity(item) //lift `item` state to `App`
  };

  return (
    <div className="item">
      <img className="image" src={item.img} alt={item.alt} />
      <ItemInfo
        name={item.name}
        price={item.price}
        onAdd={addToCart}
        onLower={removeFromCart}
        quantity={item.quantity || 0} //can access quantity directly from `item`
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't quite grasp how this part works:

`const updateQuantity = (updatedItem) => {
     const updatedItems = items.map(item => updatedItem === item ? {...updatedItem} : item) //update quantity from updatedItem  `

Are updatedItems and updatedItem two different things or is it misspelled?

Comment: Actually, I missed the part `setItems(updatedItems)`. After updating the quantity, the `updatedItem` is the changed object from `Item` component, and we need to put that updated object back to `items` which is the main state @JakeRedgrave

Comment: Got it, so now I can pass items as a prop to the Cart component and it will allow me to use quantity property there, while Item component changes the value?